# Customizing AWS Amplify Login Page: Placing Header and Footer Outside Amplify Container

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How can I customize the layout of my login page in a React project using AWS Amplify for authentication? Despite implementing a custom header and footer components, they are being contained within the Amplify container. Below is the code snippet I've used:

```
export default withAuthenticator(App, {
    components: {
        Header() {
            return (
                <div id="custom-header">
                    ..
                </div>
            );
        },
        Footer() {
            return (
                <div id="custom-footer">
                    ..
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
});
```

This is what i am getting

[This is what i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGAy.png)

I need the login page to look like this

[I need it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nydaF.png)

Any insights on how to ensure my custom header and footer render outside the Amplify container would be greatly appreciated.